# SCNAudioPlayer is throwing -10878

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I start playing an audio file like this in a SceneKit app;
It is playing the file surprisingly!

I can call first function to start playing again.

But at first call to start player I am having this message many times;
I could not find why.

**testsScene[17737:968214] throwing -10878**

```
var backgroundAudioPlayer:SCNAudioPlayer?


func someFunction(){

  DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            backgroundAudioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: "background0.mp3")
            worldNode.addAudioPlayer(backgroundAudioPlayer!)
        }

}
```

and stop in this way;

```
func someOtherFunction(){
  DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                
    worldNode.removeAudioPlayer(backgroundAudioPlayer!)

               }

 }
```

Comment: Well I am seeing this while using **AVAudioEngine** too so it must be kind of bug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with AVAudioEngine