# How to fix "throwing -10878" noise when using SKAudioNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, ios15, skaudionode

In my game built with `SpriteKit`, I have a music player in a `GameScene` declared as follow:

```
    private var backgroundMusic: SKAudioNode?
```

In `sceneDidLoad()` I instantiate it and add it to the scene:

```
    if let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GameSong", withExtension: "mp3") {
        backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(url: musicURL)
        backgroundMusic?.run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0, duration: 0))
        addChild(backgroundMusic!)
        backgroundMusic?.run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: 1, duration: 3))
    }
```

The sound is actually played as intended when the audio node is added, but I get a lot of `throwing -10878` outputs printed in the console. Running iOS 15, this occurs both on simulator and real device.

I've searched quite a bit on this site and, although there is no clear answer about why this happens, with some users guessing it is just an harmless noise, there is actually a solution [posted by Vitaliy69.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69678061/5683179)

The issue is that this is a lower level solution, and I don't really know how to implement it with `SKAudioNode`. Any way I can solve this?

**Related questions**

1. [SCNAudioPlayer is throwing -10878](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719330/scnaudioplayer-is-throwing-10878)
2. [Getting "throwing -10878" when adding a source to a mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206206/getting-throwing-10878-when-adding-a-source-to-a-mixer)
3. [In iOS 15, 'throwing -10878' occurs many times when connecting AVAudioPlayerNode to mainMixerNode](https://In%20iOS%2015,%20%27throwing%20-10878%27%20occurs%20many%20times%20when%20connecting%20AVAudioPlayerNode%20to%20mainMixerNode)